# solve the functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\phi : R-> C $ (complex numbers)

$\phi(0)=1$

$
\phi(-t) = \overline{\phi(t)} $ (
continuous and bounded)

solve the functional equation:
$Re \phi(t)= \phi(t) \overline{\phi(t)}$

This is all I know. Could someone help me solve it?

Comment: is it assumed that $\phi(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$?

Comment: I guess... I wrote all I know

Comment: Just take $ \phi(t) = 1 $ on the whole of $ \mathbb R $. C:

Comment: you can gather good bits of information:

$\phi(0)=1\Rightarrow v(0)=0$, $\phi(-t)=\overline{\phi(t)}\Rightarrow v(-t)=-v(t)$.

Comment: What does $\overline{\phi(t)}$ mean?

Comment: @kingW3 it's Complex conjugate

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't classify as an answer,though some of the info could be useful,maybe something about continuity or general solution for b(-t)=-b(t) for example.(note the last 2 expressions are quadratic formula if either of a(t),b(t) are fixed,and $a(t),b(t)$ are real-valued functions) also clearly $a(t)=1,b(t)=0$ are solutions
$$\phi(t)=a(t)+ib(t)\\\phi(-t)=a(-t)+ib(-t)=a(t)-ib(t)\implies a(-t)=a(t),b(-t)=-b(t)\\Re\phi(t)=\phi(t)\overline{\phi(t)}\\Re\phi(t)=a(t)^2+b(t)^2\\a(t)=a(t)^2+b(t)^2\implies a(t),b(t)\in[-1,1]\\a(t)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4b(t)^2}}{2}\implies b(t)\in[-1/2,1/2]\\b(t)=\frac{\pm\sqrt{-4a(t)^2+4a(t)})}{2}$$